# Get Text between Custom Tags using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am developing a Custom Programming Language that will get Converted to C# and then get compiled. How to achieve the below.

Below is a sample of my custom Language

```
Input
{
   //variables are assigned here
}
Logic
{
   //Logic is defined here
}
Output
{
   //Output here
}
```

In the above code i want to separate Input, Logic and Output into three strings,
the middle parts will have compatible C# (Common to Java too) codes. What is the best way to separate these three blocks using RegEx.

I am not using any parser because i think they will be overkill, since the actual code is c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Input[^\{]*\{([^\}]*)\}\nLogic[^\{]*\{([^\}]*)\}\nOutput[^\{]*\{([^\}]*)\}
```

Group 1,2,3 has input,logic and output content

Edit:
As you have pointed out that there can be curly braces inside it too. So this is the Updated regex.

```
Input(.*)Logic(.*)Output(.*)
```

[Tried here](https://regex101.com/r/U9rFNR/7)

Here is the sample code in c#:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"Input(.*)Logic(.*)Output(.*)";
        string input = @"Input
{
   {input is here}
}
Logic{
   logic is here
}





Output{
   output is here
}";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline;

        Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, options);
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}", m.Value, m.Index);
    }
}
```

But frankly speaking many other situation can occur. Please note that, even logic, input and output may come inside your code. therefore it would be wise to use something else to separate blocks. Say,
rather than using {}, you can use something unlikely, say #START# #END#

Comment: greate!, but think about this scenario. Input
{
   var string = " input {is here}";
}
Logic
{
   logic is here
}
Output
{
   output is here
}

Comment: I thought about it later, i will update it in a while just wait...

Comment: Input GGG
{
   input is here
}
Logic
{
   logic is here
}
Output
{
   output is here
}.... This code should not work too...

Comment: You need to set a proper format. What can sit between Input{}and Output{} ? newline, tabs, space what else ? You may have to set a rule for that otherwise it is tough to determine all possibilities